# CSS empty-cells with table header

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an HTML table and I want to hide a column if all the `td`s of the column are empty.

I used following css:

```
td.actor-custom-settings {
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

But it doesn't work becuase I have a header for this column.

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th class="actor-custom-settings"></th>
</tr>
```

Now I am using render-time algorithm to determine if there is no data in this column:

```
@if (Model.Config.Custom.Actors.All(x => x.CustomSettings.Count == 0))
{
    <style>
        .actor-custom-settings {
            display: none
        }
    </style>
}
```

Entire generation code (for a reference, it's quite irrelevant for a question):

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="actor-custom-settings">Custom Settings</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body">
        @foreach (var x in Model.Config.Default.Actors)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control actor-name" value="@x.Name"></td>
                <td class="actor-custom-settings">
                    @if (x.CustomSettings.Count > 0)
                    {
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Key</th>
                                    <th>Value</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var pair in x.CustomSettings)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="actor-custom-key">@pair.Key</td>
                                        <td class="actor-custom-value"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="@pair.Value"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs table-button-change-state" onclick="deleteTableRow(event)">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I'm wondering if there is a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understading you correctly, then you simply need to edit your CSS rule to add a second selector to target the `th` elements with the `.actor-custom-settings` class and hide them if they're empty:

```
th.actor-custom-settings,td.actor-custom-settings{
    empty-cells:hide;
}
```

Or you can simplify it to a single class selector:

```
.actor-custom-settings{
    empty-cells:hide;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that `th` is never empty. And column should be hidden if all `td`'s are empty, regardless on `th`.

Comment: either before loading check td value avail or after table load call javascript to hide the column if td's are empty

Comment: Can you update your question to include this information as it is currently unclear? You have an empty th of class .actor-custom-settings in the sample code you provided. With this clarification the answer to your question becomes no, this can't be done with CSS alone.

Comment: Confused as to why you've accepted this answer, Alex if, as you say, it doesn't actually solve your problem.

Comment: @Shaggy becuase it seems to be the best answer. Negative result is result.